# Get the cause of a Maven build failure inside a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins scripted pipeline set up where I execute a number of Maven builds. I want to treat one of them as non-fatal if the root cause is a known one.

I have tried to achieve that by inspecting the Exception's message, e.g.

```
try {
    sh "mvn -U clean verify sonar:sonar ${sonarcloudParams}"
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    if ( e.getMessage().contains("not authorized to run analysis")) {
        echo "Marking build unstable due to missing SonarCloud onboarding. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SLING/SonarCloud+analysis for steps to fix."
        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
    }
}
```

The problem is that the exception's message is not the one from Maven, but instead "script returned exit code 1".

There is no further information in `e.getCause()`.

How can I access the cause of the Maven build failure inside my scripted pipeline?

Comment: Interesting. Just a comment, but I would firstly separate the "critical" (i.e. `sonar:sonar`) part from the rest into separate Maven calls. Then I would read the error stream, and look for the message there.

Comment: @JFMeier - I am trying to access the build log right now, but `currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(x)` does not work on my Jenkins instance due to `Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild.`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the command output, then parse it containers specific message.

```
def output = sh(
        script: "mvn -U clean verify sonar:sonar ${sonarcloudParams}",
        returnStdout: true
    ).trim()

echo "mvn cmd output: ${output}"

if(output.contains('not authorized to run analysis')) {
    currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
}


// parse jenkins job build log
def logUrl = env.BUILD_URL + 'consoleText'

def cmd = "curl -u \${JENKINS_AUTH} -k ${logUrl} | tail -n 50"

def output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: cmd).trim()

echo "job build log: ${output}"

if(output.contains('not authorized to run analysis')) {
    currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
}
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work. I assume that it's because I'm using the Pipeline Maven Plugin ( https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin ) which uses a Maven Event Spy to output the logs.

Comment: I add `echo` step to print the cmd output.  please check what content in the output

Comment: @yong - it is empty, I just confirmed. The problem is that the `mvn` execution throws an Exception, so the `output` variable is never populated.

Comment: Thanks @yong. I think it's a workable solution but I'm not keen on triggering network requests to Jenkins itself from withing Jenkins jobs.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to inspect the last log lines using

```
def sonarCloudNotEnabled = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(50).find { 
    line -> line.contains("not authorized to run analysis") 
}
```

However, this does not work by default. On the Jenkins instance I'm using it errors out with

> Scripts not permitted to use method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

Comment: The exception will be printed out to job build log?

Comment: @yong - yes, it will be printed to the build log.

Comment: please see my answer, I add code example to fetch and parse build log